# Why doesn't nvcc recognize a macro that works with gcc?

Tags: c, cuda, macros

I developed a little program that uses the ReLU function. That function was defined as a macro and works well when the program is compiled using gcc.
The problem is that when the same program is compiled using nvcc it gives the error `error: expected an expression`.

An example of the code that gives the error is the following:

```
#define ReLU(x)             \
({                           \
    __typeof__ (x) _x = (x); \
    _x < 0 ? 0 : _x;       \
})

int main(){
    float x = 1.0;
    printf("%f\n",ReLU(x));
}
```

when compiled with `nvcc test.cu` it returns:

```
test.cu
test.cu(16): error: expected an expression

test.cu(15): warning #177-D: variable "x" was declared but never referenced

1 error detected in the compilation of "test.cu".
```

I can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Maybe nvcc doesn't support compound statement expressions nor typeof (both are gcc extensions), check https://github.com/AccelerateHS/accelerate/issues/234

Comment: @DavidRanieri It seams so. Trying to substitute directly the statement expression in the printf function it compiles correctly and works. Is there no way of using the macro ? Just to have a more understandable code...

Comment: @Dresult It is using GCC-specific syntax. It won't work on any other compiler (except if it specifically implements GCC's behavior, like Clang does). It shouldn't be expected to work in standard C (or C++).

Comment: Just put it into a function. It will certainly be inlined, especially in device code. There is also `__forceinline__` for making sure, although I do not think that any good compiler would not inline such a small function in a release build.

Comment: It will be possible to write this in pure standard C with upcoming C23. The rule of thumb is otherwise to avoid GNU extensions like the plague.

Comment: Also if a pre-defined list of accepted types is a feasible option, you can also write this with current standard C and `_Generic`.

Comment: At least the first GCC extension (compound statement expression) can be replaced by `do { /* ... */ } while (0)` understandable by any serious C compiler..

Comment: I guess the nonstandard constructs are all to avoid evaluating `x` twice.  If you can be sure of applying `ReLU` only to expressions without side effects, you could make it cleaner, simpler, and more portable by just writing `#define ReLU(x) ((x) < 0 ? 0 : (x))`.  But, really, paleonix is right: just make it a true function.  Function-like macros are basically obsolete.

Comment: I don't have any trouble compiling your posted code with `nvcc` from CUDA 11.4  (once I add `#include <cstdio>` of course)

Comment: @RobertCrovella I tried and the compiler still give me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define ReLU(x)             \
({                           \
    __typeof__ (x) _x = (x); \
    _x < 0 ? 0 : _x;       \
})
```

`({` *code* `})` is a gcc extension to tthe C language to alow a block of code to act as if it were an expression (and so return a value), so it's normal that other compiler don't recognize it.  Also happens to the `__typeof__` keyword, that takes the type of the argument expression to declare a variable `_x` of that same type, even if it has become a valid operator in some standard (which I've not checked actually against the standard) it is only recently in one of the last releases.